High kernel CPU usage from CcUnpinRepinnedBcb
"System" regularly takes 100% CPU on one core of my PC, so a little over 6% total on average.  This causes some extra heating and battery usage.
In trying to figure out why, I checked the active threads with Process Explorer, and the problem is consistently is within a single thread for CcUnpinRepinnedBcb.

I assumed this was normal disk access from some application, but even if I stop all foreground applications, it continues.  If I shut down several services that I recognize, it continues.
If I reboot, the problem goes away.  In fact, even if I open up my usual applications such as Google Chrome and VS Code, the problem does not immediately become present.  I have not been able to find a trigger for it.  It seems to start randomly, and I notice it when I go to undock later and realize that my CPU is running constantly.
There is only one mounted drive, my main NTFS boot drive, with BitLocker.
fltmc volumes

Dos Name                        Volume Name                              FileSystem   Status
------------------------------  ---------------------------------------  ----------  --------
                                \Device\Mup                              Remote
C:                              \Device\HarddiskVolume3                  NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2        NTFS
                                \Device\NamedPipe                        NamedPipe
                                \Device\Mailslot                         Mailslot
                                \Device\HarddiskVolume1                  FAT
                                \Device\HarddiskVolume4                  NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1        NTFS
                                \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy3        NTFS

fltmc filters

Filter Name                     Num Instances    Altitude    Frame
------------------------------  -------------  ------------  -----
bindflt                                 1       409800         0
UCPD                                    7       385250.5       0
WdFilter                                7       328010         0
storqosflt                              0       244000         0
wcifs                                   0       189900         0
CldFlt                                  0       180451         0
bfs                                     9       150000         0
FileCrypt                               0       141100         0
luafv                                   1       135000         0
npsvctrig                               1        46000         0
Wof                                     5        40700         0
FileInfo                                7        40500         0

I thought it might be SuperFetch, aka SysMain service, as when I stopped it the problem went away but it's back again and that service is stopped and disabled.

Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6860Z with Radeon Graphics 2.70 GHz
Installed RAM: 32.0 GB (31.3 GB usable)
Windows 11 Pro, Version  22H2, OS build 22621.3374

What is a good way to track down this issue?

@Gantendo This is a specific question, with the particular function already narrowed down.  Doesn't seem like a duplicate to me... if anything because I have already done the steps in the answers listed.  This is probably going to come down to some filesystem or filter driver or something, but sadly I don't know if it's visible any further with tools.

@Gantendo Good idea, I'll try it... since the problem doesn't show up until some unknown hours later and without known reason it might take me several days of trying, but I'll definitely do it as this is getting pretty wild and the single core CPU load happens to affect other things at times, like glitches in my audio.

@Brad - This is caused by a bug in the current version of the AMD iGPU driver. You can find details in this answer to this question, where someone else was having the same problem. Basically you'll need to revert to an earlier version of the driver until they fix the issue, which has been going on for a few months now.

@JohnSpeeks Awesome, thank you!!
